# HP Fortify menu is missing after install

Tags: visual-studio-2017, fortify, visual-studio-addins

I installed HP Fortify 17.20. I have clicked Next to all steps in the wizard, so all the options are default.

The problem is that the Fortify top-level menu is missing in VS2017. I am thinking this might be because the addin was installed in a wrong folder, or maybe it got disabled.

[image]

But I have no idea how to check what exactly went wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid mistake on my part, I reran the installed and made sure to check the VS2017 plugin for installation, and everything ran fine after that. I had assumed it would be installed by default but I was wrong.

[image]